# Which of "because I was taking a nap" and "because I've been taking a nap" would be natural in this context?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

A: Why haven't you contacted us before now?

B: Because **I was taking** a nap. / Because **I've been taking** a nap.

Which of these would be natural in this context?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are tons of answers dealing with the difference between these verb tenses.

Comment: Please mark as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Being super fussy, I suppose the present perfect is the more responsive answer. Technically, "I was taking a nap" might mean that I was taking a nap a year ago, which might be a true but misleading answer. The present perfect implies that, until recently, I was taking a nap.

As a practical matter, in informal writing or casual speech, either would be interpreted the same way.